# Connect distant database running with docker with no port published, from local machine via SSH key

Tags: database, docker, ssh

I have a distant InfluxDB, but it could be any database, the problem would remain the same.

In my distant machine, InfluxDB runs with docker with this configuration:

```
enedis_influxdb:
    container_name: enedis_influxdb
    image: influxdb:1.7.6
    volumes:
      - "./influxDB/influxdb.conf:/etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf:ro"
      - "/mnt/data/enedis/influxdb/data:/var/lib/influxdb/"
    networks:
      - enedis
```

So, locally, my API needs to be connected to the docker network "enedis" to access database ie API and database must run in the same machine / cluster

I have a GUI Client for influx in my local machine, I connect via SSH with a key, but then I can't figure out if it is possible to access the DB.

```
URL: dev.influx.company.fr
Docker network name: enedis_influxdb
Port use in docker: 8086
```

Note: I don't want to publish port 8086 publicly for security matters

Comment: Is publishing port 8086 and then putting up a firewall (simple `ufw` would suffice) an option?

Comment: Yes, It could be an option!

Answer (score 0):

Although you don't want to publish port 8086 on your remote machine, it's the simplest solution I see here. If you use a firewall (e.g. `ufw`), then this should not be a security problem.

[Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-18-04) you can find an excellent tutorial on how to setup `ufw` that goes into much more detail compared to what I could provide here.

As step 3 mentions there, make sure that you'll allow (at least) traffic on the SSH port, otherwise you'll kick yourself out.

Basically, what you need to run is `ufw block 8086` and your port should not be reachable from anywhere but the host machine.